# Android camera get queue's length of callback buffer

Tags: java, android, callback, android-camera

How to know the current amount of callbacks in the queue?

Sometimes the count drops to 1 callback and I only get 2 frames per second.

Setup:

```
private void setupCallback(int bufferSize)
{
    mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
    for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_BUFFERS; ++i)
    {
        byte[] cameraBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(cameraBuffer);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{
    processFrame(data);
    camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
}
```

Log says:

> D/Camera-JNI: Using callback buffer from queue of length 4

But sometimes with the same code it says:

> D/Camera-JNI: Using callback buffer from queue of length 1

How can I know that something went wrong and resetup those buffers?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in the Android API. You can move `processFrame` to another thread so that `onPreviewFrame` is essentially non-blocking. This way bulk of the queue will be within your process and you'll be able to keep track of it.

You should also note that `onPreviewFrame` is called on the same thread on which you called `Camera.open()`. If that thread is busy doing something, the `onPreviewFrame` will not be called and the corresponding buffer will drop out of the buffer pool. For this reason, I recommend that you have a dedicated thread for handling the `Camera`.

Comment: processFrame only takes 15ms. I have doubts that onPreviewFrame shoots 3-4 times during that period. Can you tell me what happens to the onPreviewFrame if previous is still processing?

Comment: I added a note on default threading. On what thread are you calling `Camera.open()`?

Comment: on a main thread. I found out what was the problem. But it didn't fix the question. UI logic was throwing an exception during which all except 1 onPreviewCallbacks were consumed. So making another thread would not fix it. I decided to resetup callbacks if the time between calls is too big.

Comment: It's not clear why a separate handler thread for camera won't resolve your problem. I don't understand why NUM_BUFFERS should be more than 2. One buffer being filled, the other being processed in your code. If your processing time is more than frame rate dictates, you will inevitably exhaust queue of any size.